# Pointer to function in C

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between the following two  statements?

```
char *(*myfunc1)(char*, int)
char *myfunc2(char*, int)
```

I know that the second statement defines a function which receives a pointer to char and an int and returns a pointer to char. I also know that `char (*myfunc2)(char*, int)`, would return a char. 
What does the extra `*` mean in the first statement?

Comment: No, the second one does not declare a function pointer (even less does it *define* it since it's a declaration).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the first one defines a pointer to a function,  the second one is a function....

so that you could do ... `myfunc1 = myfunc2`

whenever you see what looks like a function, but the name of the function is in brackets with a *   like void (*blah)( void )  it means you are defining a pointer to a function.

Answer (score 2):

The question has been answered, just thought I'd point out [this quite useful site](http://cdecl.org/) for whoever has not seen it; it has your answer.

- [char *(*myfunc1)(char*, int)](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+%2A%28%2Amyfunc1%29%28char%2A%2C+int%29).
- [char *myfunc2(char*, int)](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+%2Amyfunc2%28char%2A%2C+int%29).

Answer (score 1):

The extra `*` in the first statement means that the pointer `myfunc1` is to a function that returns `char *`.

So:

```
char *(*func1)(char*, int)  // pointer to a function that returns 'char*'
char (*func2)(char*, int)   // pointer to a function that returns 'char'
```

Comment: `char (*func)()` and `char *func()` are two very distinct things - this answer is wrong.

Comment: @H2CO3: yes, they are two very distinct things.  I don't see how that makes this answer wrong.

Comment: @H2CO3: nope, I haven't edited it.  It was correct as it stood.

Answer (score 1):

The first case  defines a function pointer  myfunc1 that returns  a char * variable.
The second case define a function, not a function pointer that returns a char * variable.

Function pointers require  parens around the  function name  (*name)